# JSON Parsing: NSArray POST

Tags: ios, json, nsarray

How to POST NSArray values in JSON or Is there any possible to POST JSON values.

Comment: *Is there any possible to POST JSON values*. Yes, there is. Case closed.

Comment: How to POST JSON values.?

Comment: that's a totally different question — and answered thousands of times.

Comment: I want to post NSArray values to JSON ?HOW?

Comment: I know how to post string values as well as files. But i have to know is there any possible to post NSArray values to json.

Comment: still answered thousands of times

Comment: If you know about that send me the link also please.

Comment: do u show some sample which type of JSON u have passed

Comment: Thank you for posting your comments.

Comment: How to POST NSArray or NSDictionary values to JSON.Its possible or not.Now i have done convert NSDictionary  values and NSArray values into  JSON.But am connecting with PHP my php code having encode and decode method with out encode and decode how can get my response from JSON? and How can get the values from that response?.

Answer (score 1):

I thing this is useful, otherwise I modify something in code

```
 NSMutableArray * arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// assume that this is your Array
[arr addObject:@"1"];
[arr addObject:@"2"];

// convert the NSArray to NSdata , the reason is always the web service get string only
NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"jsonData as string:\n%@", jsonString);
// finally append the -- jsonString to your web service
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your answers.